# Java : passing parameter to same method signature except the parameter type

Tags: java

```
public class Test{

public static void m1(Object o){
    System.out.println("object called");
}

public static void m1(String s){
    System.out.println("String called");
  } 
 }
```

Now, here are the below cases,

- m1("string"); 
  output : String called
- m1(new String("string"));
  output : String called
- Object o = "string";
  m1(o);
  output : object called
- Object o = new String("string");
  m1(o);
  output : object called
- Object o = new Object();
      m1(o);
  output : object called

Can someone please explain the above scenarios?

Comment: every of your variables `o` are defined as an `Object`, and hence it is calling `m1(Object)`. The same happens with the call with the `String`.

Comment: `Object o = "string"` performs type erasure, you've force the `String` to be considered a generic `Object`. Passing `o` to `m1()` uses the object version because that is the type of the variable `o`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision is made at compile-time, based on the type of the expression being passed in. So

- `m1("string")` uses the `String` version (since the literal is of type `String`)
- `m1(new String("string"))` uses the `String` version since the expression `new String("string")` is of type `String`
- All three of your `m1(o)` ones use the `Object` version because the type of `o` is `Object` (per the declaration)

Again for emphasis, the concrete type of what `o` refers to doesn't matter, it's the static type of the *expression* that the compiler uses to determine which overload to call.

And that means if you change the type of the expression, you can make the compiler make a different choice:

```
Object o = "string";
m1((String)o); // Calls the String version
```

There's an entire section of the JLS dedicated to method invocation expressions: [§15.12: *Method Invocation Expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). The relevant subsection is [§15.12.2: *Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2).